# How to return expected data type in PHP

Tags: php

I need to save the expected type to a variable. I have a class and the class has a property, this is the property:

```
public ?DateTime $start = null;
```

How can I access the expected data type (in this case a DateTime object)?

Comment: Do you mean something this? https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.gettype.php

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.  Please provide a small version of your class and sample code of how you are trying to access the property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [reflection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php):

```
class Test
{
    public ?DateTime $start = null;
}

$rp = new ReflectionProperty(Test::class, 'start');
echo $rp->getType()->getName(), "\n";
echo $rp->getType()->allowsNull() ? 'nullable' : 'not nullable';
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/9SoiP)